# Round very small numbers to zero (c++)

Tags: c++, rounding

Is there any command in C++ to make,

```
1.354322e-23
```

into

```
0
```

This is my (simple) Program

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

int main()
{
    float x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I type values like,

```
2.2356e-17
```

It gives,

```
2.2356e-017
```

`std::setprecision` won't work either...

**Edit:**
OK this is my problem.
I created a program that can give *sin* *cos* and and *tan* values.

For *cos* 90, I want it to be 0 instead of -4.311e-008

Heres my real program

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

float Pi()
{
  float pi = (atan(1) * 4);
  return pi;
}

int Selector()
{
  using namespace std;
  cout << "Type:\t1 for Degrees\n\t2 for Radians\n\t3 for Gradians\n\nYour Choice : ";
  int x;
  cin >> x;
  return x;
}

float D_R(float a)
{
  float q = (a / 180);
  float r = q*Pi();
  return r;
}

float G_R(float a)
{
  float q = (a / 200);
  float r = q*Pi();
  return r;
}

float All(float a, float o)
{
  using namespace std;
  std::cout << setprecision(5) << "sin(" << o << ") = " << sin(a) <<     std::endl;
  std::cout << setprecision(5) << "cos(" << o << ") = " << cos(a) << std::endl;
  std::cout << setprecision(5) << "tan(" << o << ") = " << tan(a) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  int x = Selector();
  cout << "Enter your angle : ";
  float o;
  cin >> o;

  float d = D_R(o);
  float g = G_R(o);

  if (x == 1)
All(d, o);

  else if (x == 2)
All(o, o);
  else if (x == 3)
All(g, o);
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

Ok I came up with inserting

```
if (std::abs(sin(a)) < 0.0001) a = 0; 
if (std::abs(cos(a)) < 0.0001) a = 0;
if (std::abs(tan(a)) < 0.0001) a = 0;
```

before my **All()** function

And that solved my problem

Comment: is there a reason for you not to use [floor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/)?

Comment: please refer setiosflags(ios::scientific)

Comment: floor?! sorry i'm new to c++ i don't know that!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you scared of denormals, or do you just want that numbers below some threshold are zero? In the former case, you'd set the fp environment accordingly (not a standard C++ thing), in the latter case, you'd just use `if()` or `?:`.

Comment: if you want to see a small number be zero couldn't you just have `std::cout << (int)x << std::endl;`

Comment: @JebinMatthew What is your problem here? Do you want to treat a number smaller than certain number as zero or do you want to see the same number in cout as you have input in cin

Comment: a word of caution to the reader: `std::abs()` supports floating point numbers, but if you omit the `std::` and just call `abs()` you are calling the legacy integer absolute value function and will not get a reliably correct result.  The correct legacy function for floating-point numbers is `fabs()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ can't arbitrarily round numbers down to 0 for you, it's up to you to define what a "very small number" is for your purposes.

Once you've determined the threshold, you simply need

```
if (std::abs(number) < THRESHOLD) number = 0;
```

#### RE: Your edits

> For cos 90, I want it to be 0 instead of -4.311e-008

Again, it's **up to you** to define what the threshold is. Do you want 0.00000001 to be rounded to 0? What about 0.0001? What about 0.1? **You** need to define the line where rounding occurs.

Comment: if so, where do i add it in my program in All() or in main()?

Comment: @JebinMatthew Wherever you're outputting the number.

Comment: sorry meagar, but i dont know where... Could u pinpoint the location?...(ie. at the begining of All() function or after it or somewhere else?)

Comment: Actually, the question is well-defined here. The threshold is effectively defined here by the fact that d cos(x)/dx = -sin(x), which is -1 at 90 degrees. That means that the threshold is `1 * nextafter(pi/2)-pi/2`. The underlying reason is that pi/2 cannot be exactly represented, which means there's a small error eps and thus cos(pi/2+eps) = -1 * eps.

Answer (score -1):

Probably `trunc()` does what you want.

```
#include <cmath>

cout << roundf(2.2356e-17) << " " << trunc(2.2356e-17) << endl;
```

**Output**

```
0 0
```

See Also: [`round()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/), [`trunc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/trunc/), [`nearbyint()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nearbyint/).

Comment: This isn't what was asked for.  `roundf` will round any number to the nearest integer, turning a `3.45` into a `3`.

Comment: @rm He never wrote **`only`**.